# using maltab to plot a matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix. The entries are all integers. For example, my matrix would look like this

```
M = 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3
    1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 0
    4 4 4 5 5 5 5 0 0
    4 4 4 5 5 5 0 0 0
    4 4 4 5 5 0 0 0 0
    4 4 4 5 0 0 0 0 0
    6 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 0
    6 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I wonder if matlab has some neat function to plot the boundary of these sets generated by this matrix?

Comment: I don't see a pattern within this matrix to generate this. You could use the `tril` function to generate the zeros.

Comment: It's unclear what your expected output is... is this more complicated than just `imagesc( M )`?

Comment: What about: `figure;h = bar3(M);for i = 1:length(h), h(i).CData = h(i).ZData;end`. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twTar.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a variation of `contour` plot. Don't forget that it will flip Y axis.

```
contour(M)
g = gca;
g.YDir = 'reverse';

for jj=1:size(M,1)
    for ii=1:size(M,2)
        text(jj,ii,num2str(M(ii,jj)));
    end
end
```

[image]